Diffrence between である and がある?
What is the difference between である and がある？

Most simply put, the difference between 何々【なになに】である and 何々【なになに】がある is the difference between "it is something", and "there is something".

机【つくえ】である → "it is a desk"
(as in, whatever "it" that we were talking about, that "it" is a desk)
机【つくえ】がある → "there is a desk"
(as in, a desk exists somewhere, in some context that was previously established)

